# "An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command" while opening the App

Tags: appium

I using Appium 1.5.3(Ara) version.

I'm trying to open native app and perform Login action on Emulator. When I run my code from Selenium, Emulator opens successfully, but my app does not open and throws an error: 
"An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error occured while starting App. Original error: Activity used to start app doesn't exist or cannot be launched! Make sure it exists and is a launchable activity (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)"

Desired Capabilities which I have set:

```
public void Setup() throws MalformedURLException{
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "SampleDevice");
    capabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE,"com.app-salto-new");
    capabilities.setCapability("avd", "Test");
    capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.NO_RESET, true);
    driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 }
```

Appium Logs:

```
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got data from client: {"cmd":"shutdown"}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Got command of type SHUTDOWN
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"value":"OK, shutting down","status":0}
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Closed client connection
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: numtests=1
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=.
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: id=UiAutomatorTestRunner
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: test=testRunServer
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: class=io.appium.android.bootstrap.Bootstrap
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: current=1
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: 0
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS: stream=
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] Test results for WatcherResultPrinter=.
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] Time: 3.379
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] OK (1 test)
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [UIAUTO STDOUT] INSTRUMENTATION_STATUS_CODE: -1
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
[debug] [UiAutomator] Shutting down UiAutomator
[debug] [UiAutomator] Moving to state 'stopping'
[debug] [UiAutomator] UiAutomator shut down normally
[debug] [UiAutomator] Moving to state 'stopped'
[debug] [ADB] Attempting to kill all uiautomator processes
[debug] [ADB] Getting all processes with uiautomator
[debug] [ADB] Getting connected devices...
[debug] [ADB] 1 device(s) connected
[debug] [ADB] Running /Users/srilathakondapalli/android/platform-tools/adb with args: ["-P",5037,"-s","emulator-5554","shell","ps","uiautomator"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use app launch activity in your desired caps 
capabilities.setCapability`(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY,"----")`

Comment: capabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, “com.app-salto-new”);
capabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, "nl.moboa.myclay.main.AnimationActivity");
capabilities.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY, "nl.moboa.myclay.debug/nl.moboa.myclay.main.AnimationActivity");

When I use Inspector button in Appium, app launches successfully.

Appium Logs:
[debug] [ADB] Found package: 'nl.moboa.myclay.debug' and activity: 'nl.moboa.myclay.main.AnimationActivity' ..... In all 3 situations I receive the same error, as mentioned.